# How to findout which object is not in prerequisite state in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have an java application with hibernate running over Postgresql.
And sometimes application is going to inconsistent state after

```
2017-08-01 11:50:17,317 WARN o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8080-exec-4] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 55000
2017-08-01 11:50:17,318 ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8080-exec-4] This statement has been closed.
```

I turn on postgres logs

```
 log_destination = 'csvlog'
 logging_collector = on
 log_directory = 'pg_log'
 log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
 log_file_mode = 0600
 client_min_messages = debug5
 log_min_messages = debug5
 log_min_error_statement = debug5
```

And there are no records in postgres log that indicates about some object is not in prerequisite state.

How can I find out which object is not in prerequisite state?

Comment: Figure out the contained exception, its message will tell you more.

Comment: That's big problem - there is no other exception. Only two rows in application log after three log items of select queries.

`2017-08-01 11:50:17,317 WARN o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8080-exec-4] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 55000
2017-08-01 11:50:17,318 ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper [http-nio-8080-exec-4] This statement has been closed.`
The second one is pointed that this session is become broken and it makes the application broken.

Comment: PostgreSQL does not throw an error 55000 without an error message, and the JDBC driver will propagate it as `java.sql.SqlException`. Perhaps hibernate does not show the error message, but it must be there somewhere. Can you use a debugger to dig into it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I could figure out that code 55000 is code inside postgres driver. This is not PostgreSQL status.

Answer (score 1):

In the light of the additional information from the comments, that error message originates in the JDBC driver.

The cause is that after an `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement`, `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement` or `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement` has been closed with the `close()` method, the code tries to use it again.

That is a bug in Hibernate or the application code, perhaps owing to threads that are not properly synchronized.

Comment: Yes. I have extended the postgres driver and can see that one statement (use atomic counter ) is using in different threads in the same time. 
And the most strange it (PgPreparedStatement) used for different queries. I could understand if it used for the similar queries in different threads. But not this...

Comment: After downgrading to Hibernate 4.3 from 5.2 exception is disappeared...